# Reading till new line in C++ goes in an infinite loop

Tags: c++, c++11, cin

Given the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int integer;
    cin >> integer;
    if (!cin) {
        string str;
        char ch;
        while ((ch = cin.get()) != '\n') {
            cout << "scanning" << endl;
            cout << "got " << static_cast<int>(ch) << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When given this input file (redirected input)

```
x123
```

**With a newline at the end**,  why does the program go into an infinite loop?  Shouldn't it stop after encountering the newline at the end of the file?  I keep getting the value of `ch` fetched as `-1`..

Thanks!

*Note* `cin.ignore()` doesn't seem to help resolve the issue here

Comment: It does, and then when I scan till the end to try and find a newline, I get an this infinite loop

Comment: I added in a newline manually.  It is there

Comment: Will I have to `cin.ignore()`?  Nope doesn't help

Comment: There's no code to clear the error condition, so `cin` just keeps erroring.

Comment: Apparently my brain can't function today. Sorry about that.

Comment: There are so many duplicates and variants of this it's hard to choose one. Not even hard to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get an error on `std::cin` (which is of type [std::istream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream)), then you need to clear it:

```
int integer;
cin >> integer;
if (!cin) {
    cin.clear(); // If an error occurred, we need to clear it!
    ...
```

Then it [will work.](http://ideone.com/GcOSPz)

Comment: no! it only stops the infinite loop but nothing correct!

Comment: try { cin >> integer;  if (cin.fail()) throw;} catch(...) {  cout << "cin threw this exception!" << endl;}

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to recover from the failed state with `cin.clear()` and then retry to scan till a newline..